# How to extend a class with a member of its own type?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, extends

Suppose we need to implement different types of tree with a class called "BaseNode" from which other type of Nodes are derived and it suppose to have an instance variable called `parent` of its own type, generally it looks like:

```
class BaseNode{
   //...some fields
   BaseNode parent;
   //...other methods
}
```

Now if I am going to derive Node for AVL tree with more members:

```
class AVLNode extends BaseNode{
    //...other useful stuff

}
```

the original `parent` (&`left`&`right`)node members will still be type `BaseNode` which prevents me to implement the AVL tree.
Any one who could tell me how we could solve this inheritance problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: You could do `BaseNode<T extends BaseNode>`, but I could see that causing even more problems further down the line. It would be nice to know why the type of `parent` must match the subtype that you choose to instantiate - in what way is it preventing you from implementing an AVL tree?

Comment: @VinceEmigh can't say, I guess we could find a way to circumvent this restriction and let a `BaseNode` variable to ref `parent` , but what I really want to know is how to solve this 'extend class with member of its own type' problem in general, and here I am just trying to make an example. Hopefully I can have a big picture once tried the implementation you and John Kugelman mentioned!

Comment: Are you sure that what you're attempting to do isn't a design flaw which should be avoided? It doesn't seem to affect your ability to implement an AVL tree, so yo u should ask yourself: "*Is there any real use for this design I'm trying to achieve?*" - From my point of view, I don't see *any* purpose for a design like this, which could be why the language didn't invest resources in simplifying it (designers didn't see purpose either). Could you elaborate on why you'd want to do this? In fact, a design like this seems like something a designer would typically try to avoid.

Comment: As I think of it more, I can't find even a *single* use case for a design like this. If you can find a single purpose for this, to where a design like this simplifies what you're trying to do, I believe I could shoot it down with a sturdier design. This design just seems painful: `AVLNode extends BaseNode<AVLNode>` for any potential subtype of `BaseNode` - excess verbosity for seemingly no reason. I haven't even analyzed potential issues yet, and already I'd recommend against this unless you had an actual purpose for needing this.

Comment: @VinceEmigh maybe that's true, let's say we don't really need a `parent` in the `BaseNode` but after all we definitely need `left` & `right` field in any `Node` so still we are expecting to have a class within which a member is of its own type, and certainly at some point we need to extend this class so still comes to the Question "how to extend a class like this",  I am just trying to make an example, it's not really a real-life/homework problem.

Comment: I'm going to write an answer. You seem to be a victim of design: you're attempting to apply solutions to problems that aren't there, which in turn creates even more problems. Why even have a `BaseNode` if your intentions are to create only an AVL tree? What subtypes would you have other than `AVLNode`? [Seems forced](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: @VinceEmigh appreciate！there isn’t a real problem behind this, I made this up to address the problem ’extending a class with a member of its own type’. Or You actually mean there is no such nothing cause we would never need to extend a class like that?

Comment: "*You actually mean there is no such nothing cause we would never need to extend a class like that?*" - This is exactly what I'm saying. Each design principle and pattern was invented to solve a *specific* problem. It seems you are trying to achieve this for no specific reason: what problem are you trying to solve using this design? I'm still at work, will post my answer once I get home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1** - Any time you access `parent`, cast it to `(AVLNode) parent`. You could write an accessor in `AVLNode` to make it more convenient.

```
class AVLNode extends BaseNode {
    public AVLNode getParent() {
        return (AVLNode) parent;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2** - Make `BaseNode` a generic class that takes the subclass as a parameter. Now `parent` can be the exact type needed.

```
class BaseNode<T extends BaseNode<T>> {
    T parent;
}

class AVLNode extends BaseNode<AVLNode> {
}
```

Comment: Would u give me an example about how we gonna declare a Variable of `BaseNode` and `AVLNode` w/ Solution2?